# canot post data from ionic 5 to laravel 6 using httpclint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, laravel-6

this ionic function :

```
sendPostRequest() {



        var httpHeader = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
                'ccess-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'X-CSRF-Token', 
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'csrf-token'
            })
        };


        this.httpClient.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/members/api/members", JSON.stringify(this.postData) , httpHeader)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data['_body']);
            this.presentToast(data['_body']);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.presentToast("error");
        });
    }
}
```

this "cros" middelware :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,PUT,DELET,OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Token-Auth,Content-Type,X-Requested-With',
    'application/json; charset=utf-8',  ); }
```

and this is route :

```
Route::middleware('cors')->get('/api/posts/cat/{id}','ApiPostsController@postByCategory');
```

- working in post man and online request
- middleware added to Kernel

pleae help me!

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '\*' does not work anymore on many client, you need to specify the allowed origin. postman just ignores it completely. You might want to add https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors to your laravel installation to achieve the same behavior as  '\*'